# Volusion Java Script - How to Install ROI Tracking Conversion Code

Tags: java, javascript, roi, volusion

I have installed the tracking code to the site but I need some assistance with adding the nesseasry code for getting the details of the proccessed order the provided documentation is as follows

Where Order-Specific Information is Generated

Order-specific information can be generated by JavaScript on the OrderFinished.asp page within Volusion. Two JavaScript arrays will be initialized that you may need to be aware of:

```
Order Array Contents

Order[0] = Order ID
Order[1] = Unused
Order[2] = Payment Amount
Order[3] = Affiliate Commissionable Value
Order[4] = Sales Tax
Order[5] = Total Shipping Cost
Order[6] = Billing City
Order[7] = Billing State
Order[8] = Billing Country
Order[9] = Email Address
OrderDetails Array Contents

OrderDetails[X][0] = Order ID
OrderDetails[X][1] = Order Detail ID
OrderDetails[X][2] = Product Code
OrderDetails[X][3] = Product Name
OrderDetails[X][5] = Product Price
OrderDetails[X][6] = Quantity
Note that in the above example, [X] refers to an OrderDetail line item number (beginning from zero). There may be multiple OrderDetails arrays - one for each unique item contained within an order.
```

** My goal is to get all the details of the order and be tracked with google analytics ***

my current applied code is

```
<!-- Google Code for Adwords Refferal Purchase Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1036766578;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "yqleCOCs4gYQ8pqv7gM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""         src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1036766578/?    value=0&amp;label=yqleCOCs4gYQ8pqv7gM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = '6009634664184';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
  var fpw = document.createElement('script');
  fpw.async = true;
  fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
  var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"     src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=6009634664184&amp;value=0&amp;currency=USD"     /></noscript>

<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for GI Purchase Conversion -->
<script>(function() {
var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
if (!_fbq.loaded) {
var fbds = document.createElement('script');
fbds.async = true;
fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
_fbq.loaded = true;
}
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', '6014711922784', {'value':'0.01','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none"     src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?    ev=6014711922784&amp;cd[value]=0.01&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>`
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing from the documentation is how the order variables are output on the order finished page. What you need is to add javascript to that page to push the details into Google Analytics.

Here is the code for Universal Analytics:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // Summary  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');     ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {        id: Order[0], // Order ID       affiliation: 'Convergent7', // Store name - Add yours       revenue: Order[2], // Grand Total       shipping: Order[5] , // Shipping Cost       tax: Order[4] // Sales Tax  }); // Details  for(var i=0;i<OrderDetails.length;i++) {        ga('ecommerce:addItem', {           id: OrderDetails[i][0], // Order Detail ID          sku: OrderDetails[i][2], // Product Code            name: OrderDetails[i][3], // Product Name           category: OrderDetails[i][4], // Category ID            price: OrderDetails[i][5], // Product Price             quantity: OrderDetails[i][6] // Quantity        });     } // Send   ga('ecommerce:send'); </script>
```

See the following article (Step 3) for details. http://www.convergent7.com/volusion/universal-analytics-upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion code isn't for Google Analytics... it's for Google AdWords.